# Image not loading via AJAX request ASP MVC core 3.0

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am fetching data from API controller via AJAX request all the data is loaded correctly including the Image source but I am not sure why controller name is appended to the image source and result in a broken link
Here is my code for AJAX request

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/PieData',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (jsonData) {
         if (jsonData == null) {
              alert('no data returned');
              return;
          }

          $.each(jsonData, function (index, pie) {
             var pieSummaryString = '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4"> ' +
                        '  <div class="card h-100" style="width: 17rem;">' +
                        '     <img class="card-img-top" src=' + pie.imageThumbnailUrl + ' alt="Image Not Found">' +
                        '      <div class="card-body">' +
                        '         <h3 class="card-title">' + pie.price + '</h3>' +
                        '         <h3>' +
                        '             <a href=/Pie/Details/' + pie.pieId + '>' + pie.name + '</a>' +
                        '         </h3>' +
                        '         <p class="card-text">' + pie.shortDescription + '</p>' +
                        '    </div>' +
                        '    <div class="addToCart">' +
                        '        <p class="button">' +
                        '             <a class="btn btn-primary" href=/ShoppingCart/AddToShoppingCart?pieId=' + pie.pieId + '>Add to cart</a>' +
                        '         </p>' +
                        '     </div>' +
                        '  </div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    $('#pieDiv').append(pieSummaryString);
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert(ex);
            }
        });
```

The source return by the database is "Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg" and the image source generated on the page is https://localhost:44365/Pie/Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg. Why is "Pie" is appended to the source?
JSON return by API

`{"pieId":1,"name":"Apple Pie","shortDescription":"Our famous apple pies!","price":12.95,"imageThumbnailUrl":"Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg"}`

Comment: If you return `/Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg` (note the front slash), do you still get the same issue?

Comment: The path return from the database is front-slashed. My main concern is why is "Pie" added to the image source.

Comment: the lack of a preceding slash is making the Image request relative to the directory you are in (your controller `Pie` as in `http://localhost/Pie/Images/...`) here.  Adding the front slash should make the request relative to your site root (`http://localhost/Images/...`).  Your example JSON shows the front slash being removed from the Image url. `"imageThumbnailUrl":"Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg"`

Comment: Thank You @Tommy adding the front-slash to the start of the  image source in database has fixed the problem. Many Thanks

Comment: Anytime.  I am going to copy these comments into an answer so you can accept and close.  Glad its working for ya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason for 'Pie' to be inserted into your image URL is because of the missing front slash in your JSON image path.

`"imageThumbnailUrl":"Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg"`

should be

`"imageThumbnailUrl":"/Images/PieImages/applepiesmall.jpg"`

The opening `/` in front of Images means that the image path should be calculated from the website's root directory.  When the opening `/` is missing, then the image path is calculated from the current web directory, in this case, your pie controller.